# How to ACTUALLY full screen the game view?

Tags: unity

In Unity, you can use the maximise on play option, to full screen the game when you play it. You can also double click the tab to maximise or minimize the view.

This works fine, but as you can see in the photo, technically it still leaves quite big borders around the view. This isn't really an issue, but when it comes to testing the game, having these borders is really annoying when attempting to scale things to the right size. It also feels less immersive which makes it more difficult to fine tune small details.

[image]

Both of these issues are quite important in the game that I'm making which is why I'm asking if theres a way to remove these borders and actually full screen the game without having to build/compile it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fullscreen feature was removed from Unity more than a year ago; see [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wheres-the-full-screen-option-for-game-view-in-unity-2022-2-1.1383378/).

The thread includes a link to an [Asset Store package](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/fullscreen-editor-69534) which adds support for full-screen play. I haven't tried the package and can't tell you whether or how well it works.

Comment: Thanks for the info, the package looks cool but just way too much for such a small thing like this, I was just asking in case there was a simple solution I missed.